# "Unknown MySQL server host" when using Flask in Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am trying to run a web app with Flask. I have MySQL server on my device and have changed its `bind address` to `192.168.0.102`.

Now, in Python I am attempting to connect with MySQLdb:

```
    conn = MySQLdb.connect("user='myuser', password='mypassword', host='192.168.0.102', database='usersdb'")
```

...with Flask app running on 192.168.0.102

```
app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.0.102')
```

Now, I get this error :

```
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'user='myuser', password='mypassword', host='192.168.0.102', database='usersdb'' (0)")
```

I don't know if its because MySQL is not running on 192.168.0.102
or if it is a problem with Flask.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you try to put a `string` which is invalid `host` to `MySQLdb.connection`, it's no the right params which function expect! you should read more documentations or  try to use help function to deep understand this function. and What params its require and which type of param its expected.

```
import MySQLdb
help(MySQLdb.connection)
```

you will see some docs like the below:

```
class connection(__builtin__.object)
 |  Returns a MYSQL connection object. Exclusive use of
 |  keyword parameters strongly recommended. Consult the
 |  MySQL C API documentation for more details.
 |  
 |  host
 |    string, host to connect
 |  
 |  user
 |    string, user to connect as
 |  
 |  passwd
 |    string, password to use
 |  
 |  db
 |    string, database to use
 |  
 |  port
 |    integer, TCP/IP port to connect to
```

check your mysql server running on the machine which ip is `192.168.0.102` and then try to connect your mysql server by python command line interaction :

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='myuser', password='mypassword', host='192.168.0.102', database='usersdb')
```

it's should be working!

BTW, your should run your flask on all address which your machine have! like :

```
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Comment: yap i didn't notice that, i put all the param as a string. Now it works, ty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Enter the IP address where the MySQL server is at in MySQLdb.connect:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # MySQL host, usually localhost
                       user="myuser",
                       passwd="mypassword",
                       db="usersdb")
```

And use the address `192.168.0.102` for:

```
app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.0.102')
```

Answer (score 0):

Error Because of password
Please try

```py
import urllib.parse

password = 'Ah4eg9c!5@v15{kWiT06E#S(&'
encoded_password = urllib.parse.quote_plus(password)

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(f"mysql://user{encoded_password}@host/databasename")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).